# How to Split strings, receive exception

Tags: c#

Have such problem& I have two strings:

```
a@site.ru:bvxb02lt;mu:10
b@site.ru:abc;ewfewf;tu:10
```

How to split each string with 1 function in such way:

```
string a1 = a@site.ru
string a2 = bvxb02lt
string a3 = mu
string a4 = 10

string b1 = b@site.ru
string b2 = abc
string b3 = ewfewf;tu
string b4 = 10
```

I tried :

```
string login = a.Trim().Split(';')[0].Split(':')[0].Trim();
string pwd = a.Trim().Split(';')[0].Split(':')[1].Trim();
string domain = a.Trim().Split(';')[1].Split(':')[0].Trim();
string limits = a.Trim().Split(';')[1].Split(':')[1].Trim(); // but here in second string I receive exception that Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

Comment: The reason that you're getting the exception is that your second string has two `'` characters in it.  You're essentially calling `"ewfewf".Split(':')[1]`, which is throwing the exception.  Is this input valid?  Your solution may already work as designed, and your input may just be invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this Regex you can do it:

```
(.*):(.*?);(.*):(.*)
```

so in the code you'd do something like this:

```
var matches = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
```

Here is a [Regex 101 to prove it](http://regex101.com/r/wN0gC7).

Comment: This produces invalid results for the second string - the second and third match groups should be (according to the example) `abc`, and `ewfewf;tu`.  Your answer produces `abc;ewfewf` and `tu`

Comment: I edited it so it will be less greedy and will produce `abc` and `ewfewf;tu`

Answer (score 2):

Just split them using the character array overload.

```
void Main()
{
    string input = "a@site.ru:bvxb02lt;mu:10";
    var tokens = input.Split(new char[] {':', ';' });
    Console.WriteLine (tokens);
}
```

Output:

> a@site.ru
>   bvxb02lt
>   mu
>   10

Comment: @BrunoLM: can you specify what doesn't work? The second input won't work immediatly because it requires a different split. You'll have to manually concatenate the second and third entry. All I see is you posting rather unconstructive comments on 3 working answers.

Comment: Using the second input produces wrong results, so your code in incomplete and inaccurate.

Comment: Yes, that's because the second one requires a different split criterium.I gave an example for the first one to demonstrate the concept, you can easily solve the second one by concatening `tokens[1]` and `tokens[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Split twice

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] strs = new string[]
    {
        "a@site.ru:bvxb02lt;mu:10",
        "b@site.ru:abc;ewfewf;tu:10"
    };

    foreach (var str in strs)
    {
        // 0: login 1: password & domain 2: limits
        var pieces = str.Split(new char[] { ':' });

        string login = pieces[0];
        string limits = pieces[2];

        // Split password & domain (only at the first `;`)
        var innerPieces = pieces[1].Split(new char[] { ';' }, 2);

        string password = innerPieces[0];
        string domain = innerPieces[1];
    }
}
```

Output

```
a@site.ru
bvxb02lt
mu
10

b@site.ru
abc
ewfewf;tu
10
```